# Can I run RAID5 with different cache size?

Tags: cache, raid-5, hard-drive-cache

I had RAID5 that all Hard drives are HP and has 64 mb cache (HP MB2000GCVBR).

I want to replace one hard drive but there is no one in the stock as the same (same brand and cache size).
I have found multiple Hard Drives from Different brands have bigger cache size.

Can I replace the hard drive with bigger cache than the others?

Comment: What is the exact brand and model number? SMR drives are not suitable for RAID use

Comment: It is HP MB2000GCVBR

Comment: You can find refurbished here: https://shop.ultratec.co.uk/product/658102-001

Comment: What about the cache size? Does the diffidence of cache size matters in RAID5?

Comment: As you said my HD date is Mar 2013 so I think it is befor SMR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as on-disk cache is same size or bigger it should work without any issues.
Smaller cache is to be avoided. It will in most cases still work, but you may loose a significant amount of performance.

As Chris pointed out in the comments: Also avoid drives that are of the SMR (Shingled Magnetic Recording) type. They have their uses, but they should NEVER be used in a raid environment.

Having said that...
That RAID array and its drives are at least 6 or 7 years OLD.
**Rebuilding a Raid puts a lot of strain on the remaining old drives. Often enough strain to kill another disk, while the rebuild is running.**

If that happens you have lost ALL your data on the raid array.
Don't even attempt a rebuild unless you have a very good backup, because you may need it.

If you think you can take the chance... Think again.
In my 30+ year career as IT guy I have done about 25 raid rebuilds on arrays with 5+ years old drives. I had a 2nd disk fail on 7 of those rebuilds.
These days I don't even bother. I backup the entire raid-set and restore it on a fresh set of disks if the original disk are older than 4-5 years. (It is usually also the ideal moment to put in larger disks to upgrade the overall capacity of the array.)

Comment: I believe you should mention the necessity of avoiding SMR disks. The OP hasn't told us what the brands/models are of their possible replacements and if they're looking at models with a larger cache that can be an indicator of a shingled drive

Comment: SMT is pretty rare in these smaller capacity older drives. Don't think I ever encountered one < 4 TB. But you are right. SMR is an abomination and should NEVER be put in a raid array. Added.